# Attempting to send mail with sendmail on ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: ubuntu, email, sendmail, fail2ban

I first installed sendmail on ubuntu 17.04 by running `sudo apt-get install sendmail` and then I made sure that the hostname of my machine was added to `/etc/hosts/` right after `localhost` like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost myhostname
```

I then ran `sudo sendmailconfig` and answered yes to all the questions.  I'm now trying to send some mail.  I do this:

```
echo "Subject: sendmail test" | sendmail -v me@gmail.com
```

Sendmail prints the following:

```
    ole@mki:~$ echo "Subject: sendmail test" | sendmail -v me@gmail.com 
    WARNING: local host name (localhost) is not qualified; see cf/README: WHO AM I?
    me@gmail.com... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
    220 localhost ESMTP Sendmail 8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-8ubuntu1; Mon, 14 Aug 2017 14:28:56 -0500; (No UCE/UBE) logging access from: localhost(OK)-localhost [127.0.0.1]
    >>> EHLO localhost
    250-localhost Hello localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
    250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
    250-PIPELINING
    250-EXPN
    250-VERB
    250-8BITMIME
    250-SIZE
    250-DSN
    250-ETRN
    250-AUTH DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5
    250-DELIVERBY
    250 HELP
    >>> VERB
    250 2.0.0 Verbose mode
    >>> MAIL From:<ole@localhost> SIZE=23 AUTH=ole@localhost
    250 2.1.0 <ole@localhost>... Sender ok
    >>> RCPT To:<me@gmail.com>
    >>> DATA
    250 2.1.5 <ole.ersoy@gmail.com>... Recipient ok
    354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
    >>> .
```

I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do at this point.  I tried putting a "." on a line by itself and returning but nothing happens.  If I press `ctrl C` I get the prompt back buy the email does not appear in my gmail inbox.  Thoughts?

Comment: I know from experience that Gmail has strict authentication protocols which make for a hard time with SendMail. You might have better luck with this question on https://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send Internet email directly then make `hostname --dqdn` (FQDN=Fully Qualified Domain Name) report name with existing DNS `MX` (or `A`) record.  The exact procedure is Linux distribution dependent.

You can force sendmail to use another name than auto-configured one but it is not "the best way" IMHO.